# Get a custom claim value from a bearer token with api2.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, katana

Thanks to @leastprivilege I have gotten a lot closer to what I am trying to achieve.

I have added some custom values to a claim (none of my own original work!!)

After updating the Auth.Startup file

```
  public partial class Startup
{
    static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "self";

        UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // transform claims to application identity
        app.UseClaimsTransformation(TransformClaims);


        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);



        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //    consumerKey: "",
        //    consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //    appId: "",
        //    appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
    }

    private Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformClaims(ClaimsPrincipal incoming)
    {
        if (!incoming.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<ClaimsPrincipal>(incoming);
        }

        // parse incoming claims - create new principal with app claims
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "foo"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "bar")
        };

        var nameId = incoming.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (nameId != null)
        {
            claims.Add(nameId);
        }

        var thumbprint = incoming.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Thumbprint);
        if (thumbprint != null)
        {
            claims.Add(thumbprint);
        }

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity("Application");
        id.AddClaims(claims);

        return Task.FromResult<ClaimsPrincipal>(new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
    }

}
```

I try to access the claim type Role via

```
var cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities;
```

However digging through I can't seem to find any reference to ClaimTypes.Role.

Am I trying to access the role in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Order matters in OWIN - put the claims transformation *after* the token middleware.

Comment: I moved it after //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(); however I still don't see anything. Am I putting this in the incorrect spot?

Comment: Maybe it would if you only post the parts of the startup that you actually use...

Comment: I'm sorry but im not getting it. I assume I need  app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions); Or should I be removing this to use app.UseClaimsTransformation(TransformClaims); ?

Comment: Put claims transformation after app.UseOAuthBearerTokens... then verify your transformation function gets called - if the input principal is correct etc...

Comment: Yes I had tried that before. TransformClaims is called and    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "foo"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "bar") is added however within an api controller I try  var cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities I cant find any of the ClaimTypes.Role. Is it something silly I am missing?

Comment: Use the Request.GetRequestContext().Principal or .User to get to the principal. Which claims are you seeing?

Comment: Ok so I have 4 available claims nameidentifier,name,identityprovider & role. So it's looking like the TransformClaims is not saving the application claims. Within my StartUp.Auth file I have           app.UseClaimsTransformation(TransformClaims); (at the end of the ConfigureAuth method) is there anything else I need to do to enable this? I seems like I have missed a step somewhere along the way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47349/discussion-between-diver-dan-and-leastprivilege)

Comment: What was the result of this?